# what is a temporary variable

Tags: java, methods, nested, temporary-objects

How come when I write this code the 'number' in the method is stored as a 'temporary value'? This is the first time I have came across this.

1. What is the advantage?
2. what is the disadvantage?
3. why does this happen?

package lecture18;

```
public class TemporaryVariable 
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int number= 4;
    number++;
    System.out.println(number);

    add(number);

    System.out.println("But the actual value stored in memory is:"+ number);

}
public static void add(int number)
{
    number = 17;

    System.out.println("this is the number using the method " +number);
}

}
```

Comment: Where do you see anything about it being a 'temporary value'? Regardless, the add method doesn't make much sense because you're simply overrwriting the number variable to be 17, not adding 17 to it.

Comment: What do you mean by "temporary value"? Assigning to `number` in `add` just changes the value of the local parameter; it does not affect the value of the variable by the same name in `main`.

Comment: google for "Java pass by value".

Comment: @yts My lecture said it was a temporary value because it doesn't effect the main method. this was the example he gave us. Ill look up pass by value

Comment: By that definition, all variables are temporary, because all variables are passed by value. Passing a value (a primitive value or a reference to an object) as argument always makes a copy of this value (i.e. a copy of the primitive value or a copy of the reference)